# Which abelian categories have homological dimension 1?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, quiver-varieties

In this MSRI lecture [Geometry of Quiver Varieties I](https://youtu.be/73B4zezHqh0?t=614), Victor Ginzburg describes all abelian categories of homological dimension $1$ as being either

- a category of representations $\mathrm{Rep}_\mathbf{k}Q$ of a quiver $Q$, or
- a category of coherent sheaves on a smooth algebraic curve, or
- one of fifty isolated exceptions that we don't care about.

What are these isolated exceptions? Or to answer this question more generally, what's a reference for this whole classification?

Comment: There exists a classification of hereditary abelian categories (that are noetherian, and have Serre duality) due to Reiten--Van den Bergh. His list is missing out on *stacky curves* (seen as hereditary orders in Reiten--Van den Bergh). One could argue that the ones which do not have a tilting object, nor are stacky curves, are "isolated", but it's not a finite list.

Comment: What about Dedekind domains? To me the number fifty sounds like he is not too serious about this.

Comment: I don't know what he refers to, but to give some references regarding the first two: There is a classification of Ext-finite abelian categories with a tilting object, see e.g. [Happel: A characterization  of  hereditary  categories  with  tilting  object] and [Happel-Reiten: Hereditary abelian categories with tilting object over arbitrary base fields]. Over an algebraically closed field it consists of representations of quivers and coherent sheaves over weighted projective lines.